# Migration from Angular 4 to 9

Tags: angular, migration, angular8, angular9

It is advisable to migrate Angular 4 to 9 directly, or it would be better to go from 4 to 7 and then from 7 to 9?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but have you tried just upgrading to Angular 9 and see what kind of issues you encounter? Of course make sure you have a backup of your project either in source control or some other place so you can easily restore things should you encounter too much problems.

Comment: I'm going to try, thanks you.

Comment: Generally speaking: The lower the "jumps" between major versions, the better. Your best bet is to gradually upgrade your way up to angular 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using this link https://update.angular.io/ to what you have to do for each version upgrade , i think you have to first upgrade you app from Angular 4 to 5 because of changing http and httpClient big changes come in version 5 after it i think the  other versions will be easy . 
and don't forget if your not using Angular Cli first put your project based on it.

Comment: thank you for the suport